# Javascript 'hasAttribute' don't works on data-attributes

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

I have this situations:

```
//first situation:
<div id="div" data-attr="value">My div</div>
script:
var id = document.getElementById('div');
if(id.hasAttribute("data-attr")){...
//second situation:
//second situation:
<div id="div">My div</div>
script:
var id = document.getElementById('div');
id.setAttribute('data-attr','value');  
if(id.hasAttribute("data-attr")){...
```

The second example don't work: i want know why?

Edit:
setAttributeNode was just a typo, I used setAttribute

Comment: Why don't you use `dataset`?

Comment: try using `setAttribute` instead - considering that code will fail

Comment: @JaromandaX — ?! How would that help?

Comment: `gelElementById` — You misspelt `get`. (Voting to close off topic because the problem was caused by a typo)

Comment: @Quentin - because using setAttribute is how you set an attribute - [setAttributeNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttributeNode) does something completely different, and the OP's code should fail with an error

Comment: @JaromandaX — The question is asking about `hasAttribute` … which doesn't (appear to) work when the attribute is set with plain HTML.

Comment: fair enough - but my comment is still valid, `.setAttributeNode` is being used wrong in the code - once he fixed gelElementById, this would be the next point of failure

Comment: Now Stop: You are focused on typing errors.
Are you a developer or not? Did not you realize that they were typing errors? Focus rather on the real problem and not on these gaps, as none of your statements solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use `dataset` property, example below.

```js
let div = document.getElementById("data");
if (div.dataset.foo) {
  console.log("data", div.dataset.foo);
}

let empty = document.getElementById("data-empty");
empty.dataset.foo = "bar";
if (empty.dataset.foo) {
  console.log("data-empty", empty.dataset.foo);
}
```

```html
<div id="data" data-foo="bar"></div>
<div id="data-empty"></div>
```

And if you want to go with your code then it's working properly.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div');
if(div.hasAttribute("data-attr")){
  console.log("div", div.getAttribute("data-attr"));
}

var empty = document.getElementById('div-empty');
empty.setAttribute('data-attr','value');  
if(empty.hasAttribute("data-attr")){
  console.log("div-empty", empty.getAttribute("data-attr"));
}
```

```html
<div id="div" data-attr="value">My div</div>
<div id="div-empty">My div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a typo in your code:

var id = document.ge**l**ElementById('div');

it should be:
var id = document.ge**t**ElementById('div');

Then, include your JS code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div">My div</div>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var id = document.getElementById('div');
        id.setAttribute('data-attr','value');
    </script>
</html>
```

Hope this could help,
Laura.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it was just a typing error, I copied and pasted the first part of the code, and in the hurry I did not notice it. Unfortunately 'id.setAttribute (' data-attr ',' value ');' It does not work, as I had already written, that was the problem ...

Comment: Don't warry, it's common enough ;)